# Heightmap in Shader not working

Tags: hlsl, heightmap

I'm trying to implement GPU-based geometry clipmapping and have problems to apply a simple heightmap to my terrain. For the heightmap I use a simple texture with the surface format "single". I've taken the texture from [Catalinz's XNA blog](http://www.catalinzima.com/tutorials/4-uses-of-vtf/terrain-rendering-using-heightmaps/).

What I'm trying to do is just getting the single float value from the texture at the vertex world coordinate and apply the value to the Y-Value of the Vertex. I'm applying the heightmap through the shader, because there is no fixed grid in-code it could be applied on. What I've tried so far was using the `tex2Dlod` function, but there seems to be no output or an output of 0. The Direct X vertex shader's code looks like this:

```
float4 worldPos = mul(float4(pos.x,0.0f,pos.y, 1.0f), worldMatrix);
float elevation = tex2Dlod(HeightmapSampler, float4(worldPos.x, worldPos.z,0,0));
worldPos.y = elevation * 128;
```

Where `HeightmapSampler` is a point-mirror sampler of the heightmap texture. Here is the output, I actually get no elevation:

[image: Screenshot]

And here's the heightmap I'm using:

[image: Heightmap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot that Texture coordinates are in Texels, so multiplying it with the texels fixed it.

```
float elevation = tex2Dlod(HeightmapSampler, float4(worldPos.x*texel, worldPos.z*texel,0,0));
```